# How to initialize TextView to avoid NullPointer error?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn how to use bound services. Whenever I click the Start/Pause button I would like for the timer to change as desired. However, clicking these buttons will kill the program. I'm not sure why this TextView object is giving a NullPointerException error in my service class. Could someone please help me with this?

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    //Binder
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    Button btnStart,btnPause,btnLap;
    TextView txtTimer;
    Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    LinearLayout container;

    long startTime=0L,timeInMilliseconds=0L,timeSwapBuff=0L,updateTime=0L;


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            //Return this instance of LocalService so public methods can be called
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-startTime;
            updateTime = timeSwapBuff+timeInMilliseconds;
            int secs=(int)(updateTime/1000);
            int mins=secs/60;
            secs%=60;
            int milliseconds=(int)(updateTime%1000);
            txtTimer.setText(""+mins+":"+String.format("%02d",secs)+":"
                                        +String.format("%03d",milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this,0);
        }
    };
}
```

This object has already been initialized in my Main class here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocalService mService = new LocalService();
    boolean mBound = false;
    Button btnStart, btnPause, btnLap;
    TextView txtTimer;
    LinearLayout container;
    Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    long startTime=0L,timeInMilliseconds=0L,timeSwapBuff=0L,updateTime=0L;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnPause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
        btnLap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLap);
        txtTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
        container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(mService.updateTimerThread,0);

            }
        });

        btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                timeSwapBuff=+timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(mService.updateTimerThread);
            }
        });

        btnLap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,(ViewGroup)null);
                TextView txtValue = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textContent);
                txtValue.setText(txtTimer.getText());
                container.addView(addView);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }

    //Define callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService()
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName mainActivity, IBinder service) {
            //We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalService.LocalBinder binder = (LocalService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {

        }
    };
}
```

When this service is running I would like for the txtTimer in my main activity to be updated with the bound service values. I'm getting a NullPointer error code taking me to LocalService class around line 56:

```
txtTimer.setText(""+mins+":"+String.format("%02d",secs)+":"
                            +String.format("%03d",milliseconds));
```

Whats the best way to update this so that txtTimer is able to show the changing value? I would really appreciate some help

Comment: Where do you assign a value to your `Service.txtTimer`?

Comment: within the Runnable block, second to last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define this constuctor on  `LocalService` class :

```
public LocalService(TextView textView){
   txtTimer = textView;
   super();
}
```

and add this line before  `btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View ...` :

```
mService = new LocalService(txtTimer);
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thank you! this helped, super(); of course needs to be called first in that function, but I'm able to build on this

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `txtTimer` object is never initialized in your service. Modifying UI elements from a service is tricky, and best not actually done directly from the service itself.

Generally, the solution to this is to implement a `BroadcastReceiver`. You'll simply send whatever data you want (in this case, a string) to your activity, which will then act upon receiving that data.

First, in your service, you create an `Intent` object, in which you'll put a `Bundle` with whatever data you want to send to the activity:

```
Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-startTime;
        updateTime = timeSwapBuff+timeInMilliseconds;
        int secs=(int)(updateTime/1000);
        int mins=secs/60;
        secs%=60;
        int milliseconds=(int)(updateTime%1000);

        // Get the data to send
        String string = ""+mins+":"+String.format("%02d",secs)+":"
                +String.format("%03d",milliseconds);

        Intent intent = new Intent("MainActivityListener");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("txtTimerString", string);

        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        // Send broadcast
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

        customHandler.postDelayed(this,0);
    }
};
```

Then in your activity, you'll need to create your `BroadcastReciever`, which will receive the string you want from the service and set your TextView accordingly:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            String txtTimerString = extras.getString("txtTimerString");
            if (txtTimerString != null) {
                txtTimer.setText(txtTimerString);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And then finally, you'll need to register the `BroadcastReciever` in the `onResume` method of the activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, 
            new IntentFilter("MainActivityListener"));
}
```

This is a lot safer than trying to find a way to pass the TextView directly into the service, since the service can run independently of the activity. If the service were to try to modify the TextView and the activity isn't currently running, you'd likely crash. This way, the service simply puts out a broadcast - and if the activity isn't running, it doesn't matter.